# How to integrate javascript into spss

Tags: javascript, spss

How can I run a script so when a user leave current window of survey then it'll popup a dialog. I know that in javascript I can use:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

But I don't know how to integrate it into SPSS, I've used IOMScript routing items but seem like it does not understand javascript. Please help :(